# Fill textbox from url query and call function

Tags: javascript

```html
<input type="text" id="tnum" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Your Tracking ID" /> 
<input class="btn" type="button" value="TRACK" onclick="doTrack()" />
<div id="YQContainer"></div>
```

So basically, I have a page that can track packages for my customers. I want to be able to send them a link in their email that will automatically track their package from the link. ( they don't have to type in their tracking id and click track when they go to my tracking page )

example.com/track?tnum=3298439857

This is what i'm using to track packages.

https://www.17track.net/en/externalcall/single

Comment: You can use `window.onload` event and check `window.location.href` in a listener. If your url is what you need - call your function in the listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic idea is as follows:

1. Wait for page to load
2. Parse the URL and extract needed query parameter
3. Set the value of the form element
4. Call the `doTrack()`  function

```js
// Handy function to parse the URL and get a map of the query parameters
function parseQueryParameters(url) {
  var qp = {};
  if (!url) {
    return qp;
  }
  var queryString = url.split('?')[1];
  if (!queryString) {
    return qp;
  }

  return queryString.split('&')
    .reduce(function(m, d) {
      var splits = d.split('=');
      var key = splits[0];
      var value = splits[1];
      if (key && value) {
        m[key] = value;
      }
      return m;
    }, qp);

}

//Wait for page to load
window.onload = function() {
  //Extract tnum query parameter
  var qp = parseQueryParameters(window.location.href);
  //If no parameter is provided, do nothing
  if (!qp.tnum) return;
  //Set the value of the form element
  document.getElementById("tnum").value = qp.tnum;
  // Call doTrack
  doTrack();

}

//Temporary doTrack function - remove when integrating ;)
function doTrack() {
  console.log(document.getElementById("tnum").value)
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="tnum" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Your Tracking ID" />
<input class="btn" type="button" value="TRACK" onclick="doTrack()" />
<div id="YQContainer"></div>
```

Comment: So this is a page that people can enter the tracking id themselves and click the track button, which then would show the tracking of their package. But, I want to be able to send emails and insert the tracking number into the url for them, and have it automatically track it when they get to the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
    function setURL(){
    var dt_value = document.getElementById("tnum").value;
    //just test here ..what is coming..
    alert(dt_value );
    var sjdurl =  "example.com/track?tnum="+dt_value;

popup = window.open(sjdurl,"popup"," menubar =0,toolbar =0,location=0, height=900, width=1000"); 
popup.window.moveTo(950,150); 

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="Text" id="tnum" maxlength="25" size="25"/>
  <input type='button' onclick='setURL()' value='SUBMIT'> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function doTrack(tnum) {
  var trackNumber = tnum;
  window.open("example.com/track?tnum="+trackNumber);
}

$(".btn").on('click',function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var tnum = $('#tnum').val();
  if (tnum!="") {
    doTrack(tnum);
  } else {
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.